# How to animate text in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, text

I am trying to animate a text box in a Matplotlib figure, but can't seem to get it working. Does anyone know how to do this properly? An example is below.

```
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

times = ['first', 'second', 'third']

time_text = ax.text(.5, .5, '', fontsize=15)


def updatefig(num):
    global mt
    mt = ax.text(.5, .5, times[num], fontsize=15)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, frames=len(times)-1, blit=True, init_func=init)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Text is an `artist` and you animate it exactly like any other `artist`:

```
def updatefig(num):
    time_text.set_text(times[num])
    return time_text,
```

Comment: I know this is old, but how do you also update the location of the text on the graph?

Comment: I would assume you use something like `time_text.set_x(x[num])` and `time_text.set_y(y[num])`